# IME Keyboard class keycodes vs KeyEvent class keycodes in Android

Tags: android, keyboard, keycode, ime

Does the `Keyboard` class have its own keycode for each character than the `KeyEvent` class? If so, where can I get a keycode list for all characters for the IME `Keyboard`?

For example, in `Keyboard` `android:codes`, we use `97` for the 'a' key, but the Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent#KEYCODE_A) for `KeyEvent` tells the keycode for 'a' is `29`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) part of the documentation lists all the KeyCodes present in the SDK. All keyboards use these keycodes to allow you to input things.

Comment: Thanks you , but i mean the Android:KeyCode , Eg.: 'a' = 97 , i cant see it in your link

Comment: If you click on any particular keycode, you can see the constant value in the JavaDoc. For example, `a` is `29`.

Comment: so , why '97' also output 'a' ? By the way , iam looking to show a Input Method Selection on a Long press key , does i have to Ceate this Myself , or is there an option in Android to show this (to choose between Different Keyboard/Input Methods) ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two keycode or (code ) that you are talking about

- **Keycode** in KeyEvent [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html)
- **Code** in IME (Input Method Editor)  [reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html)

They are both used in different areas but in your cases, it mentions about the "character" display when user press they soft keyboard and that makes you confused.

For better understanding of the IME, please see the Android sample app which comes with the SDK.

Please noted that in IME, Upper case & lower case use the same code. You might need to use

```
KeyboardView.setShifted(boolean)
```

Hope it helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting confused in differentiating between the keycodes used in the XML attribute `android:codes` of Android's [`Keyboard.Key`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.Key?hl=en#attr_android:codes), which uses the keycode, for example, of 'a' as `97`:

```
<Key android:codes="97" android:keyLabel="a" />
```

and the keycode value referenced in the Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent#KEYCODE_A) which uses `29` for the same:

```
public static final int KEYCODE_A = 29;
```

So, **WHY??**

If you see the documentation for `Keyboard.Key`, you will find that `android:codes` define the [**Unicode**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Latin_script) for the key.

And indeed, if you see the implementation in the [`KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener#onKey(int,%20int%5B%5D)), we first convert the keycode from `int` to `char` before
calling [`inputConnection.commitText()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputConnection?hl=en#commitText(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int)).

```
     @Override
     public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
         InputConnection inputConnection = getCurrentInputConnection();
         
         if (inputConnection != null) {
             switch(primaryCode) {
                 default:
                     char code = (char) primaryCode; // Here we convert keycode from int to char on the basis of Unicode values
                     inputConnection.commitText(String.valueOf(code), 1);
 
             }
```

While, the keycode values documented on Android's website are the constants *defined* in [`KeyEvent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent) class. They are used to identify the key, in a `KeyEvent`. If you want you can assign that in `android:codes` attribute and then, use the `sendKeyEvent()` to input the text.